# Using an iterator on a table

Tags: kdb

I have this table:

```
A:2.34889 2.484112 1.045939 3.359097 1.642348 1.298948 3.046995 4.077684 
B:3.845017 3.762336 3.287893 3.338063 5.861462 5.401914 3.537128 5.27197
t:([] AA:A;BB:B)

-1 + prd select (-1#AA)%(1#AA) from t 
-1 + prd select (-1#BB)%(1#BB) from t
```

which outputs

```
AA| 0.7360047
BB| 0.3711175
```

I was wondering how I can modify the last two lines into a single line that iterates over AA and BB? For example, if I had 10 symbols, I would only have to write a single line to output the 10 results.

Also apologies on the question title, I am not sure how to phrase it well but am happy to edit if required.

Answer (score 3):

Iterators on tables can either be row rise (demonstrated by 0N! below):

```
0N!/: t
`AA`BB!2.34889 3.845017
`AA`BB!2.484112 3.762336
`AA`BB!1.045939 3.287893
`AA`BB!3.359097 3.338063
`AA`BB!1.642348 5.861462
`AA`BB!1.298948 5.401914
`AA`BB!3.046995 3.537128
`AA`BB!4.077684 5.27197
```

Or column wise with flip:

```
0N!/: flip t
2.34889 2.484112 1.045939 3.359097 1.642348 1.298948 3.046995 4.077684
3.845017 3.762336 3.287893 3.338063 5.861462 5.401914 3.537128 5.27197
```

For this case, you could do the latter and apply your function to all columns with the each iterator:

```
{-1+prd last[x]%first x} each flip t
AA| 0.7360047
BB| 0.3711175
```

Use `#` or `select` to get the subset of columns you want to apply the function to if needs be:

```
{-1+prd last[x]%first x} each flip `AA`BB#t
AA| 0.7360047
BB| 0.3711175
```

More generally, when trying to build up similar code to apply to a list of columns functional form can be useful to be aware of:  https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/

```
parse "exec AA:{-1+prd last[x]%first x} AA from t"
?
`t
()
()
(,`AA)!,({-1+prd last[x]%first x};`AA)

// or cls:cols t
cls:`AA`BB ;

?[t;();();cls!({-1+prd last[x]%first x}),/:cls]
AA| 0.7360047
BB| 0.3711175
```

Comment: Thanks! I am slightly confused about the row-wise and column-wise table. Wouldn't the table in my question be a column-wise table? However, I might be wrong since `{-1+prd last[x]%first x} each flip t` gives the correct answer. Appreciate any clarification on this!

Comment: This is in reference to how you apply iterators to a table. When you apply each with a table on the right and a function on the left. Each row will be applied to the function. In order to apply each to each column, you need to flip the table first as shown. 0N! Is showing what values would be fed into each iteration

Answer (score 3):

Matts answer is a better and more general answer but in your particular example the logic can be as simple as:

```
q)-1+last[t]%first t
AA| 0.7360047
BB| 0.3711175
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to iterate through the columns.

The best use of iterators here is [Each Left](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right) to apply both `first` and `last` to `t`.

```
q)(last;first)@\:t
AA       BB
-----------------
4.077684 5.27197
2.34889  3.845017
```

That table is a 2-list, so you can apply Divide.

```
q)-1+(%).(last;first)@\:t
AA| 0.7360047
BB| 0.3711175
```

To define this for re-use, it’s a composition of three unaries, here spaced for clarity:

```
q)f:-1+ (%). (last;first)@\:
q)f t
AA| 0.7360047
BB| 0.3711175
```

Works for any number of columns.